# oidc-client: grant.type=password additional grant options are not supported

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-oidc

I have just started playing around with quarkus-oidc-client to obtain tokens form our Ping-Identity server.

In case of quarkus.oidc-client.grant.type=password additional grant options are not supported as only password.username and password.password are considered while initializing the tokenGrantParams (see https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/extensions/oidc-client/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/oidc/client/runtime/OidcClientRecorder.java#L154)

Our Ping Identity server requires an additional grant option (password.validator_id). Are there any plans to support additional grant options in case of password grant? Are there any workarounds?

Thanks Thomas

Comment: "*Are there any plans to support additional grant options in case of password grant?*" - This might be better asked through the [Quarkus GitHub Repo](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus) or in the [Quarkus Zulip Chat](https://quarkusio.zulipchat.com/).

Comment: see https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/21415

Comment: Hi, PR is here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/21448, thanks